# Replacing bytes in TMemoryStream

Tags: delphi

I am sending data over internet as TmemoryStream , now i want to encrypt it using a simple algorithm.

So i thought about replacing each and every **byte** in the tmemorystream to encript it.

looks like

> **eg(a memoryStream in bytes):**
>
> [123] [233] [122] [001] [123] [233] [122] [001] [123] [233] [122] [001]
>
> **eg(password in ascii)**
>
> hi = [72] [73]
>
> **encription**
>
> [123 + 72 ] [233 + 73 ] [122 + 72] [001 + 73] [123+ 72] [233 + 73] [122 + 72] [001 + 73]  [123 + 72] [233 + 73] [122 + 72] [001 + 73]
>
> **Final Value**
>   [195] [51] [194] [74] ...

How can i do this kind of replacement in a single parse using Delphi

**and**

How to replace a byte in a memeorystream in a single parse to achieve this.

======================= update ==============================================

```
var pq: integer ;
....
    LLine := // from a stream

        //start blocjk
           //my encription
               p := LLine.Memory;
                  for i := 0 to LLine.Size-1 do
                  begin

                   pp := p^ ;
                   pq := pp + 72 ;

                   if pq > 255 then
                   begin
                     pq := pq - 255 ;
                   end;
                   P^ := Byte(pq) ;


                    inc(p);
                  end;

                // my encription end
                //my decription
               LLine.Position := 0;
         p := LLine.Memory;
                  for i := 0 to LLine.Size-1 do
                  begin

                   pp := p^ ;
                   pq := pp - 72 ;

                   if pq < 0 then
                   begin
                     pq := pq + 255 ;
                   end;
                   P^ := Byte(pq) ;


                    inc(p);
                  end;
        //end

        //end blocjk





        Image1.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromStream(LLine);
```

Comment: How would you decompose the wrapped [233 + 73] -> [51] back to [233 + 73] ?

Comment: @AlexK. can you substract 73 from 51 (73 is a char in passowrd) else it will reduce 22 for 255

Comment: I don't like your algorithm. better use XOR encryption, or even better use real stream encryption like RC4 which is easy to implement.

Comment: If I had this task, I wouldn't replace the TMemoryStream contents. Instead, I'd write a TStream *wrapper*, give the wrapper a reference to the memory stream, and then give the wrapper to whatever code was previously receiving the memory stream. When the consumer calls `Read` on the wrapper, the wrapper would call `Read` on the wrapped stream, "encrypt" the result, and then return to the caller. The wrapped stream can be anything, including a TMemoryStream, a TFileStream, a TResourceStream, or some other stream class that hasn't even been written yet.

Comment: How can `pq` be < 0 if you store bytes (and then you read integers)?

Comment: @kobik It's <0 after the subtraction of 72. Much easier to intentionally overflow as per my answer mind you.

Comment: ooops... I have missed that line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TMemoryStream` exposes a property named [`Memory`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Classes.TCustomMemoryStream.Memory) that points to the first byte of the stream. So you can do something like this:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  p: ^Byte;
...
  p := MemoryStream.Memory;
  for i := 0 to MemoryStream.Size-1 do
  begin
    EncryptByte(p^);
    inc(p);
  end;
```

Where `EncryptByte` would be defined like this:

```
procedure EncryptByte(var b: Byte);
```

and modified the byte it was passed in-place.

For your trivial encryption scheme you could write the code like this:

```
  p := MemoryStream.Memory;
  for i := 0 to MemoryStream.Size-1 do
  begin
    inc(p^, 72 + (i mod 2));
    inc(p);
  end;
```

I've been a bit lazy here and written the modification directly into the loop since it requires knowledge of the current index.

You will want to make sure that range checking is disabled for this block of code.

---

The error in your code, in the updated question, is that you need to shift by `256` rather than `255`.

```
if pq > 255 then
begin
  pq := pq - 256;
end;

...

if pq < 0 then
begin
  pq := pq + 256;
end;
```

Comment: What else are you looking for? Ideas on how to implement the encryption?

Comment: @vibeeshanRC you can use a simple XOR encryption algorithm, there are many delphi examples out there.

Comment: If you need easy random access you can cast .Memory to a PByteArray instead.

Comment: @vibeeshanRC inc(p) is fine and the code in my answer is fine. The memory stream is just a block of memory. I take a copy of the pointer to the first byte of that block and then step through it. `Position` is what you use when treating it as a stream and calling `Read` and `Write`. `p^ := value` will work, but so will the code in the answer. I don't know what your problem with that code is.

Comment: I just put your code in middle of my code(to encrypt) , and i assigned it to a jpeg image (LoadFromStream),at this point it must show an error but unfortunately it is working correctly(without decryption)!!!!!!!! I can see the image

Comment: Something else at play here. My code works. Try dumping encrypted to a file, or writing each byte to a text file. Write a simple unit test for the encryption code. It is fine. Your version is fine too.

Comment: I don't know what is happening  if i remove //start blocjk to  //end blocjk everything works ok, So the problem is in my code. and it is impossible to dump it to a file and reading it as it is a jpeg file

Comment: Test the encryption on some trivial data that you invent. Then apply to the jpg file. Might I ask why you are setting Position?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6822/discussion-between-vibeeshanrc-and-david-heffernan)

Comment: Very hard to say what your problem is but modifying the buffer as I describe works just fine. I can't do much more for you.

Comment: @vibeeshanRC, David's answered your initial question correctly. the problem is your so called "encryption algorithm". I'm down-voting (for the first time) your question.

Comment: @kobik I've answered the follow-up question too. It turns out it wasn't so hard!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , My special thank to you for spending some time on solving my problem